# ASP.NET losing session variables while uploading a file

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am using jQuery uploadify plug in to  upload files in ASP.NET .Before uploading file i can able 
 to   access session variables like userId.But when i click on upload immediately i am losing session variables.It is giving null when i access Session[_UserId] .What might be the reason.What mistake i am doing?

Can any one help me?

Comment: You should probably provide the uploadify config options you're using and anything else that may be relevant.

Comment: are you using session in your handler file?

Answer (score 0):

To upload an image via this plugin i believe you used a ashx handler and probably you are using session in to that.

In order to get session, the handler class must implements IReadOnlySessionState interface.

Example :

```
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
    // your stuff
}
```

Hope this will help !!